# Parallel tree construction: No performance improvement

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, tree, task-parallel-library

I'm constructing a bounding volume hierarchy tree using a recursive tree construction algorithm:

```
    protected void Subdivide(BoundingVolumeHierarchyNode node, HeFace[] faces)
    {
        if (node.Depth > Height)
            Height = node.Depth;

        if (!NeedsSubdivision(node))
        {
            Debug.Assert(faces.Length > 0);
            node.Triangles = faces;
            return;
        }

        List<HeFace> subsetA = new List<HeFace>(0);
        List<HeFace> subsetB = new List<HeFace>(0);

        MedianPartitionStrategy str = new MedianPartitionStrategy();
        str.ParitionObjects(node, subsetA, subsetB, faces);

        node.Left = new BoundingVolumeHierarchyNode(node.Depth + 1, CreateAabrFromFaces(subsetA.ToArray()), subsetA.Count);
        node.Right = new BoundingVolumeHierarchyNode(node.Depth + 1, CreateAabrFromFaces(subsetB.ToArray()), subsetB.Count);

        Debug.Assert(subsetA.Count > 0);
        Debug.Assert(subsetB.Count > 0);

        //var left = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subdivide(node.Left, subsetA.ToArray()));
        //var right = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Subdivide(node.Right, subsetB.ToArray()));

        //try
        //{
        //    Task.WaitAll(left, right);
        //}
        //catch (AggregateException)
        //{
        //    //handle exceptions here
        //}
        Subdivide(node.Left, subsetA.ToArray());
        Subdivide(node.Right, subsetB.ToArray());
    }
```

My algorithm is pretty slow, so I tried to speed it up by constructing the tree using parallel tasks.
The commented code executes the construction in parallel. I've benchmarked parallel execution vs. single execution:

- parallel: 00:00:14.6067970
- single threaded: 00:00:15.2736202

So the improvement is very small. 
My processor is an Intel Core 2 Quad. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly you only need to create one task, for say Left, the do the work for Right in the current thread, and then wait for the task.

Comment: Some of the results of this search MAY help you http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[task-parallel-library]+tree

Comment: How much work does each task do, compared to the effort to fork that work?  If the answer is "not much", you'll get no benefit.  The secret is to make work per fork ratio high.  If you are doing a recursive partition, you might consider doing forking only in the "high" parts of the tree, and NOT forking the low parts for some definition of low.  By varying the definition of low, you can control work per fork to your advantage.

Comment: @Ira Baxter That's a great idea. I'll try it!